# Reading PDF file using Android

Tags: android, pdf

I'm developing a Application for Android that read PDF files.

I want my Program to Copy a Block of text from a PDF file and transfer it to my program and store it in a variable. How do you do that?

Do i need to use a application to do that? or there is a code for doing it? I have seen **filereader** library in android development site(correct me if im wrong). I havent tried it yet because im busy with other projects that i have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can download [PDFbox API](http://pdfbox.apache.org/) to read PDF in android.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Jaguar. does this Api Read Tables and Pictures in PDF? or it only read the whole content as text?

Comment: It depends: is your PDF tagged? If so, the PDF contains content as well as structure. If the PDF isn't tagged, the PDF only contains snippets of text drawn on a canvas. The PDF isn't aware of any tabular structure. As for pictures: I don't know PDFBox well enough. I only know that it's possible with iText and that iText is the fastest tool on Android: http://stefan.fenz.at/creating-pdfs-on-android-an-evaluation/

Comment: how will i know if its tagged? I tried copying the content of PDF file in Word and its in text form even the text is enclosed in a table.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a go at [PDFjet](http://pdfjet.com/os/edition.html) to handle PDF files in Android and can check out some [examples](http://pdfjet.com/java/by-example.html) given here.